# VS Unit Test Results file (.trx) is not displayed into SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-msbuild-runner, sonarqube-5.4

I have setup SonarQube with the following:

- sonarqube-5.4
- MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.0
- VS 2013 (target .net framework 4.5.1)
- SQLServer2014 Express Edition
- Windows7Professional SP1 64bit OS

I used the above settings and able to publish the code analysis results into SonarQube. I followed the below link to publish the unit test results (.trx) file: http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389772

I have added the below tag in the "begin" command to pick up VS unit test results file.

```
/d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="C:\TestResults\\*.trx"
```

Below parsing details captured from the bottom of console window:

```
19:48:58.788 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpUnitTestResultsProvider$CSharpUnitTestResultsImportSensor
19:48:58.798 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio Test Results file C:\abc_ABC 2016-04-29 19_45_36.trx
19:48:58.828 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpUnitTestResultsProvider$CSharpUnitTestResultsImportSensor (done) | time=40ms
```

But unit test details are not shown in the project dashboard / Code Coverage tab. Are there any settings or configuration needs to be done (C# plugin added already)? How can we see the unit test results in SonarQube?

Please find the attached screenshot for the project dashboard.
Where can we see the unit test results ?

On clicking the second tab "Coverage", it shows the message - "This component does not have coverage details."

[image: ProjectDashboard]

Comment: By project dashboard, do you mean the homepage when you click on the project from the sonar landing page? They don't show on that page. You need to actually open the dashboard page.

Comment: Please refer to the project dashboard screenshot attached above and provide navigation path to see the unit test results. Thanks.

Comment: The trx file doesn't include coverage information, only pass fail information. It should be visible by clicking on the project level dashboards menu item from your screenshot, then the first option.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Dashboards --> Custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on  Mike Barry's comments,

Go to project level Dashboards menu item --> Custom.
It will show unit test results table / widget as well.